# Secure iptables logging against DDoS

Tags: iptables, logging, ddos

My server is blocking all IP addresses except Slovakia and Czech Republic, and I would like to log all other countries and then drop it.

So my rules looks like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m geoip ! --src-cc CZ,SK -j LOG_COUNTRY
```

then I have LOG_COUNTRY chain like this:

```
iptables -N LOG_COUNTRY
iptables -A LOG_COUNTRY -m limit --limit 5/s --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "COUNTRY DROP: "
iptables -A LOG_COUNTRY -j DROP
```

I would like to ask you how to "secure" it against DDoS, I set limit, so it should be fine.

But if someone will DDoS me, I would like to get all these IP addresses from DDoS attack, and I don't know if limit 5/s can log all attacker's IP addresses.

I don't know what limit number is considered as safe, I don't want to log same IP addresses and packets multime times per second, rather I would like to log as much different IP addresses as possible. I hope you understand me.

Comment: I don't think this config will help against a DDoS.  I don't know if any confiig can help.  I hope someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: It is not "against" DDoS, it is for logging all IP addresses of that DDoS.

Comment: There's no guarantee that you will catch every single one of them, but if the attack goes on long enough, you'll have most of them.

Comment: It is that question if is possible to drop same packets and different packets log and then drop. And another subquestion is.. what limit number is safe, if 1000/s limit is overkill or so. I use SSD.

Comment: Just freewheeling here.  Wir schaffen dass!   Don't block, but direct those requests to a tool that keeps a hash table of the IP addresses and logs every new one.  Perhaps HaProxy with a sticky table?

Comment: haproxy with a stick-table is a great idea that Gerard mentioned.  You could also use xt_recent assuming you can change modprobe settings `options xt_recent ip_list_tot=1000 ip_pkt_list_tot=20` and then periodically capture the table from `/proc/net/xt_recent/name` that you create in a rule.  Another way would be `ipset` and add the attackers dynamically to an ipset list then periodically read, merge and sort the list with a saved copy.

Comment: Thank you, and how can I dynamically add IP to ipset via iptables?

Comment: Use the `SET` module: `-j SET --add-set myset src --exist`